# How to change the URL of a non cms page?

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I need to customize the URLs for my site and would like to know how to change them. With CMS pages its very straightforward but I would like to know how to do it with a non cms page. Thank you

Comment: can you provide at least 1 or 2 examples?

Comment: Well say I want to change the url for my contact us page. atm the url is index.php/contacts but I would like to change it to something like index.php/contact-us

Comment: If possible, try to make these changes from admin panel, you can get this via URL Rewrite Management feature.

Comment: Once the url is changed, how can i make it so that in the footer where it says 'contact' it still links to the same page

Comment: this still makes no sense as i have no idea what i am supposed to use as the ID Path?

Answer (score 1):

You can create small module, which will rewrite module routers.

For example for Contact Us page it will look something like:

Create file

> app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and second file

> app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Contacts</module>
                    <frontName>contact-us.html</frontName>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```